# How to get hibernate internal properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, generator, sequence

I want to use hibernate's TableGenerator for custom key generation

```
final SessionImpl session = ((SessionImpl) EntityManagerUtils
            .getEntityManager("CORE").getDelegate());

TableGenerator generator = new TableGenerator();



    Properties params = new Properties(??????????);
    // params.put("identifier_normalizer", ?);

    params.put("table_name", "eflow.docs_number_generators");
    params.put("value_column_name", "tbl.GENERATOR_VALUE");
    params.put("segment_column_name", "tbl.GENERATOR_KEY");
    params.put("increment_size", "25");
    params.put("segment_value", "2011");
    generator.configure(IntegerType.INSTANCE, params, session
            .getSessionFactory().getDialect());

    Serializable id = generator.generate(session, new Object());
    System.out.println(id);
```

But object with key "identifier_normalizer" is missing and this snippet throws null pointer exception. This object is of type `ObjectNameNormalizer` which normalizes db object names and is stored in hibernate local mappings.

how to access hibernate's internal mappings and consequently this `ObjectNameNormalizer` object ?

Actually as it seems i will need hibernate Mappings object which i don't know hot to get.

Thanks in advance

Comment: me three! Surprised that not many people interested in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes the solution:

```
  private String generateKey() {
    final SessionImpl session = ((SessionImpl) em.getDelegate());

    if (generator == null) {
        synchronized (TableGenerator.class) {
            if (generator == null) {
                generator = new TableGenerator();

                ObjectNameNormalizer normalizer = new ObjectNameNormalizer() {

                    @Override
                    protected boolean isUseQuotedIdentifiersGlobally() {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected NamingStrategy getNamingStrategy() {
                        return new Configuration().getNamingStrategy();
                    }
                };
                Properties params = new Properties();
                params.put("identifier_normalizer", normalizer);
                params.put("table_name", "eflow.docs_num_generators");
                params.put("value_column_name", "GENERATOR_VALUE");
                params.put("segment_column_name", "GENERATOR_KEY");
                params.put("increment_size", "25");
                params.put("segment_value", "2011");
                generator.configure(IntegerType.INSTANCE, params, session
                        .getSessionFactory().getDialect());
            }
        }
    }

    Serializable id = generator.generate(session, new Object());
    return id.toString();
}
```

Comment: wow. kinda crazy your solution. you write the generate method yourself